# DocuSign status for reminders API

Tags: docusignapi

When a reminder is sent from DocuSign, does this action come down in the API status data as "Sent" or does it come down at all?

Are there any reports at DocuSign that show how many reminders have been sent?

Using REST API.

Answer (score 1):

By API status data you mean a notification message from a DocuSign webhook?

I don't believe that the current notification messages indicate that a reminder has been sent or not. The easiest way to test is to use the [webhook recipe](https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/recipes/webhook-status) and then use the web panel to send a reminder to the signer.

**Updated**

The [Envelopes: listAuditEvents](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/listAuditEvents/) may include the reminder messages. Test it and let us know.

Comment: the listAuditEvents does not show reminders being sent either.

Comment: I did use the Getnotification on some sample envelopes and the settings are correct for expire and reminders. I would like to be able to update the application for when reminders are sent but cannot find an API call that returns this information.